# Representing uniqueness on a restricted domain

Tags: prolog

Given some functions:

```
define foo(x,y) (x > y) end.
define bar(x) (foo x x) end.
define baz(x,y) (foo x y) end.
```

I am not interested in the exact values that a function takes/returns however I would like to know about how the *sign* of an input affects the output.

To model the greater than function I use the atoms `zero_int` which is interpreted as `0`, `pos_int` which is interpreted as all integers greater than `0` and `neg_int` interpreted as all integers less than `0`.

```
%% pos_int greater then ...
%% i.e forall n,m : (n > 0) & (m = 0) => n is_greater_than m
gt(pos_int,zero_int,true).
gt(pos_int,neg_int,true).
gt(pos_int, pos_int, X) :- boolean(X). % return either true or false.
%% zero greater than ...
gt(zero_int, pos_int, false).
gt(zero_int,zero_int,false).
gt(zero_int, neg_int, true).
%% neg int greater than...
gt(neg_int, pos_int, false).
gt(neg_int, zero_int, false).
gt(neg_int, neg_int, X) :- boolean(X).
```

the `boolean/1` predicate is used to return either `true` or `false` when there is a choice point. i.e comparing `n > m` where `n > 0` and `m > 0` may be be either true or false. As we do not know the actual (integer) values of `n` and `m` assume that both cases are true.

```
%% define booleans
boolean(true).
boolean(false).
```

Now I encode the functions in the following way:

```
foo(X,Y,Return) :- gt(X,Y,Return).
bar(X,Return) :- foo(X,X,Return).
baz(X,Y,Return) :- foo(X,Y,Return).
```

testing `foo` (and `baz`) we get expected results:

```
?- foo(X,Y,Return).
X = pos_int,
Y = zero_int,
Return = true ;
X = pos_int,
Y = neg_int,
Return = true ;
X = Y, Y = pos_int,
Return = true ;
X = Y, Y = pos_int,
Return = false ;
X = zero_int,
Y = pos_int,
Return = false ;
...
```

My issue is that because `bar` calls `gt` with a single value - I would like for it to always return `false` as it is never the case than `n > n`

```
?- bar(X,Return).
X = pos_int,
Return = true ;
X = pos_int,
Return = false ;
X = zero_int,
Return = false ;
X = neg_int,
Return = true ;
X = neg_int,
Return = false.
```

I am interested in how one might encode this. I have explored using pairs of variables as inputs that would allow for *labels* which could be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
boolean(true).
boolean(false).

gt2((_, pos_int), (_, zero_int), (_,true)).
gt2((_, pos_int), (_, neg_int),  (_,true)).
gt2((L1, pos_int), (L2, pos_int), (_,X)) :- not(L1 == L2), boolean(X).
%% zero greater than ...
gt2((_, zero_int), (_, pos_int),  (_,false)).
gt2((_, zero_int), (_, zero_int), (_,false)).
gt2((_, zero_int), (_, neg_int),  (_,true)).
%% neg int greater than...
gt2((_, neg_int), (_, pos_int), (_,false)).
gt2((_, neg_int), (_, zero_int), (_,false)).
gt2((L1, neg_int), (L2, neg_int), (_,X)) :- not(L1 == L2), boolean(X).

gt2((L,pos_int),(L,pos_int),(_,false)).
gt2((L,neg_int),(L,neg_int),(_,false)).

foo(X,Y,Return) :- gt2(X,Y,Return).
bar(X,Return) :- foo(X,X,Return).
baz(X,Y,Return) :- foo(X,Y,Return).
```

This uses the idea of *labels* which allow us to *tag* inputs such that we can encode equality. Basically if the labels match then the input is *strictly* equal. (ie given two inputs that within the *set* of positive integers, if they have the same label, then they *are* the same integer.
which would give the results:

```
?- bar(X,R).
X =  (_31408, zero_int),
R =  (_31414, false) ;
X =  (_31408, pos_int),
R =  (_31414, false) ;
X =  (_31408, neg_int),
R =  (_31414, false).

?- foo(X,Y,R).
X =  (_31852, pos_int),
Y =  (_31858, zero_int),
R =  (_31864, true) ;
X =  (_31852, pos_int),
Y =  (_31858, neg_int),
R =  (_31864, true) ;
X =  (_31852, pos_int),
Y =  (_31858, pos_int),
R =  (_31864, true) ;
X =  (_31852, pos_int),
Y =  (_31858, pos_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X =  (_31852, zero_int),
Y =  (_31858, pos_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X =  (_31852, zero_int),
Y =  (_31858, zero_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X =  (_31852, zero_int),
Y =  (_31858, neg_int),
R =  (_31864, true) ;
X =  (_31852, neg_int),
Y =  (_31858, pos_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X =  (_31852, neg_int),
Y =  (_31858, zero_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X =  (_31852, neg_int),
Y =  (_31858, neg_int),
R =  (_31864, true) ;
X =  (_31852, neg_int),
Y =  (_31858, neg_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X = Y, Y =  (_31852, pos_int),
R =  (_31864, false) ;
X = Y, Y =  (_31852, neg_int),
R =  (_31864, false).
```

notice that `foo` generates an extra input for when the *labels* are the same.